# Retrieve ID with query in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve an ID from my database. This code is in the file **ControllerUtil.php**

```
public static function getTableCell($verifiedObject, $client_id, $key) {

    $connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "password", "database");
    $query = "SELECT check_id FROM check_latest WHERE `key` = '{$key}' AND client_id = '{$client_id}';";
    $check_id = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return "<td id='{$check_id}'</td>";
}
```

And here is the code from my **index.php**

```
<?= ControllerUtil::getTableCell($result->offline, $result->id, "offline") ?>
```

`$verifiedObject equals $result->offline` (not important in this case)
`$client_id equals $result->id` (for example 1)
And `$key` equals `offline` in this case

So there query looks like this

```
SELECT check_id FROM check_latest WHERE `key` = 'offline' AND client_id = '1';
```

When I execute this code in the database I get my desired result. However when I execute the above code in PHP it doesn't work.

Comment: mysqli_query returns mysqli_result class, not id. http://php.net/manual/zh/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call select query with mysql function in php your $check_id is a collection that can be convert to a row data with :

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
    $check_id = $row[0];

//some code here
}
```

Notice: In this case your query can be return multi rows.